# Chrome Extension - Fix img tag onerror infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, error-handling

I would like to fix a particular bug of a website with an extension I'm making.

(going to explain the site in simple terms)

The website has an album and the way it works is that each album has an x amount images and each image has its own page for example: `1.html`. On each page is a single image of which i assume are dynamically generated. For some reason sometimes on the last page of an album the img tag looks like this:

```html
<img id="image" src="mainsite.com/album1/images/" onerror="this.src='mainsite.com/album1/images/'">
```

So this results in chrome being stuck in an endless loop logging the following:

`Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "mainsite.com/album1/images/".`

This causes my computer and I'm sure anyone else's who use the site to lag real bad as a result of this bug.

I wish to fix this issue with an extension so my question is, is it possible to fix this problem with an extension? if so, how? I've tried setting the onerror and src attribute to an empty string and it seems the src of the img is constantly being updated somehow which results in the error still going off.

[Here's](http://mangafox.me/manga/one_piece/vTBD/c770/17.html) an example of the problem (warning! it may lag your chrome if you stay on page too long)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `onerror` *attribute*:

```
document.getElementById('image').removeAttribute('onerror');
// or if you use jQuery: $('#image').removeAttr('onerror');
```

Using `img.onerror = null` within a content script does not work, because of the [isolation of JavaScript execution contexts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment):  the page's `onerror` *property* is invisible to your content script.

Comment: ahh so that's why it wouldn't work, thank you so much, it works now :)

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, here's a jQuery-free solution:

```
<img src="image.png" onerror="this.src='image.png'; this.onerror = null" />
```

Comment: Completely and utterly irrelevant.

Comment: @Xan, how is this irrelevant? It has the exact same functionality as the accepted answer except it doesn't rely on jQuery.

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nk9aocx/)

Comment: You're proposing to do _what_, exactly? The code of the website is not in OP's control. He's building an extension to interact with it.

Comment: Oh, I see the issue. The OP is not the author of the website in question. My mistake.

The owner of the website should fix the issue...

Comment: The question boils down to "what can an extension do to fix it". And RobW's answer shows why it's not straightforward.

Comment: I think the simplest answer here is for OP to report the issue to the site owner. It's a bug!